# Register Open Generic with dotnet core 3

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm trying to register an Open Generic type in my application but I'm having a strange behavior.

The following is working correctly:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IA<>), typeof(A<>));
```

Now, I would like to pass parameters to my `A` class, because my constructor has some arguments:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IA<>), provider =>
{
    return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(provider, typeof(A<>), "1", "2");
});
```

This generates an exception

> 'Open generic service type 'IA`1[T]'
>   requires registering an open generic implementation type. (Parameter
>   'descriptors')'

Ok so I simplified my factory, and just did something like this:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IA<>), provider => typeof(A<>));
```

But this generates exactly the same exception.

Question is simple: How to register an Open Generic with parameters with the default .net core DI ? (I don't want to use a third party library like Castle Windsor)

Note that the constructor of `A<>` has optional parameter, this is why `services.AddTransient(typeof(IA<>), typeof(A<>));` is working

Comment: can you modify the constructor of `A<>`?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the constructor of `A<>` parameters into a class and inject it instead of passing the parameters

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IA<>), typeof(A<>));
services.AddTransient<AOptions>(sp => new AOptions { X = "1", Y = "2" });
```

```
public class A<T> : IA<T>
{
    private readonly AOptions _aOptions;

    public A(AOptions aOptions = null)
    {
        _aOptions = aOptions;
    }
}

public class AOptions
{
    public string X { get; set; }
    public string Y { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's a good solution but it doesn't explain why the one with the provider is not working?